# Regarding functions from R² to R: continuity and differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative, differential

Let $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set and $P \in U$.

I am almost sure the following statements are correct, but please confirm:

1. The only requirement for $f$ to have a tangent plane at $P$ is: $\exists \  \nabla f(P)$ (in other words, both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist at $P$. **Edit:** *the partial derivatives must be continuous!*
2. If the tangent plane exists, still not necessarily the function is continuous at $P$.
3. The statement 2 is reverse order: if the function is continuous at $P$, still not necessarily the tangent plane exists.
4. If the function happen to be continuous at $P$, still not necessarily the function is differentiable at $P$.

And now, assuming those are correct, my main question comes:

***If $f$ is continuous at $P$, and $f$ has a tangent plane at $P$, is it possible that $f$ still is not differentiable?***

I might have misunderstood what my teacher said, but it seems that the answer is yes! If you agree, can you provide at least one example?

Thank you!

---

**EDIT (Six months later):** This question awarded me the Tumbleweed badge and even after six months there hasn't been any answers, comments or even votes! Today something made me remember of this question. **Fortunately, I already made some progress:** I was able to confirm the statements 1, 3 and 4. I couldn't confirm statement 2 yet, and my main question also still stands (I put it in italic above). Thanks for any help.

---

**EDIT 2 (May 28):** Thanks for the attention. I have felt the need to quote James Stewart in his definition of tangent plane:

> Suppose f has continuous partial derivatives. An equation of the tangent plane to the surface $z = f(x, y)$ at the point $P(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is
>   $$z - z_0 = f_x(x_0, y_0)(x - x_0) + f_y(x_0, y_0)(y - y_0)$$

Therefore, Stewart needs only continuous partial derivatives to define the tangent plane.

This shows that I was wrong about my **statement 1**. I have edited it now, adding the "must be continuous" requirement. This doesn't change any of my other thoughts though (yet).

I would like to emphasize that I am considering **any** weird function you could come up with, not just real life functions and such. In this question I am looking for properties that will formally apply in any case.

**If anyone disagrees that statements 1, 3 and 4 are true please comment for further discussion (maybe I did miss something!).**

**Now I'll try to give an example of what makes me believe in statement 2:** Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Take this weird function:

$$ f(x, y)=\begin{cases}
    0, & \text{if $x = 0$ or $y = 0$}.\\
\\
    1, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases} $$

Hopefully, if I'm not mistaken, this function is an example that shows that my second statement is true. (please let me know if I'm mistaken).

**Assuming everything is fine by now, don't forget of my main question:**

> *If $f$ is continuous at $P$, and $f$ has a tangent plane at $P$, is it possible that $f$ still is not differentiable?*

Comment: How do you define a tangent plane? The definition I'm familiar with requires that $f$ is differentiable at the point, the existence of the partial derivatives is not sufficient for that definition. Consequently, continuity at a point is a necessary condition for the existence of a tangent plane at that point then.

Comment: Thanks for your support! According to my Stewart Calculus book, 7th edition (translated), the tangent plane at $P = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is defined as the plane whose equation is $z - z_0 = f_x(x_0, y_0)(x - x_0) + f_y(x_0, y_0)(y - y_0)$, and does not need conditions except the existance of $f_x$ and $f_y$. Stewart even comments the fact that if the function is not differentiable, the tangent plane will give a terrible approximation to the function. But the tangent plane still exists.

Comment: Hmm, I had the impression that Stewart assumes the partial derivatives are continuous when he defines the tangent plane, cf. the conversation between John Jack and me starting [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20433655#20433655). It seems he doesn't, going by your comment. Which means his definition differs from everybody else's (well, perhaps not _everybody_ else).

Comment: Wait, you're right!! Sorry about that! Indeed the partial derivatives must be continuous! I missed that. But is that equivalent to differentiability? (I will now look at the link you mentioned).

Comment: It's not equivalent, it's stronger than differentiability. A function can be differentiable at a point without the partial derivatives even existing at any other point. But such examples are pathological, in cases one "naturally" comes across, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok. Maybe we could proceed discussing in a chat? Not now though, I gotta go. But I still think none of those statements implies the other. I will be happy to discuss it deeper with you later. Thanks. By the way, I have no idea how to start a chat, maybe you could that for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Like Daniel mentions in the comments, you have to first very carefully define what you mean by a "tangent plane."

Here's how I might do it: for any differentiable curve $\gamma: [-1,1]\to U,\ 0\mapsto P$, the tangent *vector* associated to $\gamma$, if it exists, is given by 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\gamma(t), f(\gamma(t))\right]_{t\to 0}.$$

I'd say a tangent *plane* exists at $P$ if (i) the tangent vector exists for all $\gamma$, and (ii) they span a two-dimensional linear space.

Existence of the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ is not enough to guarantee both of these conditions. Consider the standard counterexample

$$f(x,y) = \frac{(x-y)^2}{x^2+y^2}.$$

Here are a few $\gamma$ and their tangent vectors at $P=(0,0)$:
\begin{align*}
(t,0) &: (1,0,0)\\
(0,t) &: (0,1,0)\\
(t,t^2) &: (1,0,-2)
\end{align*}
these already span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so I would not say a tangent "plane" exists at $P=0$.

2. Existence of a tangent plane means that the limit of $f(x,y)$ as you approach $P$ along any path must be equal to $f(P)$, and so $f$ is continuous.
3. Certainly not.
4. Nope.

To summarize:

$$\nabla f \textrm{ exists and continuous} \Rightarrow f\textrm{ differentiable} \Leftrightarrow \textrm{tangent plane exists} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}f_x, f_y \textrm{ exist}\\f \textrm{ continuous}\end{cases}$$

Comment: A differentiable function need not have a continuous gradient.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Quite right; fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I like your idea to define a tangent plane, but I will have to study it more carefully later, to guarantee that I fully understood it. I am curious to see if your definition is equivalent to Stewart's definition (that I quoted on my newest edit on the question), or if it is stronger.